# Confusion about result of pre and post decrements

Tags: java

I recently started learning java in my computer science class and i came accross something interesting.
Basically i have my variables set as the following 
`int x = 5;`

I created an expression `x = (x--) - (--x)`
when i print the variable x it always results as `2`, no matter what the variable `x` is.

The exact code is:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class MathOperations extends ConsoleProgram {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run(){

        setFont("arial-bold-24");

        int x = -5, y = -3;
        double z = 2.2;

        x = (x--) - (--x);

        println ("x= " + x);
    }

}
```

Why is the result always 2?

Comment: Is your question "Why is the result always 2?"?

Comment: yes, how do you arrive to that result

Comment: And after @rgettman posted his answer, it should suffice it to say that you are never supposed to do funky stuff like that with pre and post decrement.

Comment: This could be figured out by printing `x--` and `--x` then subtracting them

Comment: Yeah I finally got it now thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is always `2`, for any `int` you can use.  The reason:

`(x--)` is evaluated first, because operands are evaluated left-to-right.  This yields the original value, `x`, but afterwards, `x` is original `x` - 1.  Then `(--x)` is evaluated.  It returns `x - 1`, which was already decremented once, so the result is original `x` - 2.

From there, it's simple math, `x - (x - 2)` is `2`.

But what about possible underflow in the decrement?

```
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
x = x-- - --x;
System.out.println(x);
```

The result is still `2`.  How?  Integer.MIN_VALUE is:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Decrementing it twice will yield `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`.

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

Subtraction in 2's complement notation yields

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
```

or `2`, even if underflow takes place.

That is true for any integral type: `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`.

Interestingly, it will also be true for *most* common floating-point values, such as `2.2`.

However, if the precision of the floating-point type is more than `1`, then the result of the decrement operation will *not* change the value.  In this case, the result will be `0`.

```
double x = (double) (1L << 54);
x = x-- - --x;
System.out.println(x);
```

Result:

```
0.0
```

Comment: I'd add that expression are evaluated from left to right, unless parentheses set a different priority.

Comment: Also, just be aware of underflow for "any `int`"

Answer (score 0):

Java evaluates operators with a fixed [order of precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  This line of code `x = (x--) - (--x)` has 4 operators: Prefix--, postfix--, subtraction, assignment.  Ordered by precedence, they are postfix--, prexfix(unary)--, subtraction(additive), and assignment.  This makes your statement operate in  this order:

1. `x = 5 - (--x)`:  x (5) is decremented after this operation
2. `x = 5 - (3)`: x is decremented again from it's previously decremented value to 3
3. `x = 5 - 3`
4. `x = 2`